# Visual Studio parsing behavior with custom property sheet to set platform tools version

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

i am in the process of converting a large set (over 600, hard to manage manually or via script) of projects from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2013.

In order to keep the compiler version (and possibly other values) as modular as possible and build the projects with the VS2010 compiler from within VS2013, i define it in a custom property sheet (called native multi targeting, see [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx) and [this blog](http://manski.net/2012/01/sharing-project-properties-in-visual-c/)).

My stripped down custom property sheet (located in the project folder named my_properties.props) looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup Label="Configuration">
        <PlatformToolset>v120</PlatformToolset>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

It is imported in the project at the topmost position, as can be seen in the Property Manager

[image: Property Manager]

which means it will overide all settings previously defined (though not relevant here, this was tricky to figure out).

Now to the problem. Depending on the order of imports in the project, the default platform toolset is correctly set to Visual Studio 2013 (v120) or not, in which case it is reverted to Visual Studio 2010 (v100), no clue where this is defined.

My stripped down project looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
      <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
        <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{396A761A-45C9-46AA-BCF0-59FFD306D674}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>platform_toolset</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <!-- This is Block A -->
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <!-- /A -->
  
  <!-- This is Block B -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- /B -->
  
  <!-- This is Block C -->
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
    <Import Project="my_properties.props" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <!-- /C -->
  
  <!-- This is Block D -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- /D -->
  
  <!-- This is Block E -->
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
    <Import Project="my_properties.props" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <!-- /E -->
  
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
</Project>
```

With this ordering of the blocks, A, B, C, D, E, from top to bottom i get a default platform toolset of v100 for Debug builds and v120 for Release builds, oh boy.

Moving Block A to the end gives v120 for Release and nothing (empty field) for Debug, so A in front seems important (which would make sense for default/basic other property sheets from Microsoft).

Moving the ImportGroups in front of the PropertyGroups (resulting in A, C, E, B, D) leads to the correct behavior, v120 for Debug and Release and it is "inherited" (not bold).

How would i ensure the right order for my project files to be safely able to define the platform toolset centrally? Isnt MSBuild breaking a basic XML rule here be introducing an order of elements?

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148396/how-to-set-platformtoolset-from-custom-property-sheet-in-visual-studio-2010) gave some important hints ("ms warns ... order ..."), [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e7331f38-19dd-4efc-9525-12729d0b9521/how-to-set-the-default-platform-toolset) thread actually asks in the same direction.

Even in the bad cases, i can expand the Makros and have the following values, which seem fine to me:

> $(DefaultPlatformToolset) v120
>
> $(PlatfromToolset) v120
>
> $(MSBuildToolsVersion) 12.0
>
> $(VCTargetsPath) ...\V120\

A MSBuild bug? I know, property sheets are a bit icky, you have to restart the Studio if property sheets changed, some values (e.g. environment variables) seem to be cached, etc.

Any input is highly appreciated!

PS: Using VS2013 Update 3 on a Windows 7 64bit machine.

Comment: Now that MSBuild is opensource, one could look in its code what exactly it does: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/03/18/msbuild-engine-is-now-open-source-on-github.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The platform should be set in the very beginning, like described in the link you posted. It is used in the Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props / Microsoft.Cpp.props.

The 'v100' you get could come from one of the .user files. Do you really need/have them? 
I mean, here:

```
<Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
```

I mean, they are basically only useful for custom building on a specific user computer. If you don't use any computer- or user- specific settings, you can just remove those. These "user-settings" files are located in your user profile folder.

Also mind that "Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" normally goes before "Microsoft.Cpp.props".

Anyways, faced similar issue, I ended up removing all the stuff from the projects (.vcxproj) files at all. Then it seems to work pretty well. And clean. In your case, it would look like this.

.vcxproj (note that nothing related "debug" or "release" or ".user" or whatever is inside).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<PropertyGroup>
  <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
  <ProjectGuid>{49C9EA4B-99DC-47D1-B32E-ACDF297B2A43}</ProjectGuid>
</PropertyGroup>

<Import Project="Platform.props" />
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />

....

<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />  

</Project>
```

Platform.props (shared for all .vcxproj files)

```
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<PropertyGroup>
  <PlatformToolset>v120_xp</PlatformToolset>
  <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
  <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
    <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform>Win32</Platform>
  </ProjectConfiguration>
  <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>Win32</Platform>
  </ProjectConfiguration>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Ok, so the order is indeed important, how would i script this with e.g. python? After all it is XML and there should not be an order. I have a lot of projects to maintain, no way to do this manually. I will try your proposed reordering on monday, putting the "my_properties.props" before the MS related imports. The user defined props are basically empty. thanks!

Comment: *After all it is XML and there should not be an order* it really are MsBuild files and as such have a specific evaluation order

Answer (score 1):

Yes, MSBuild file is XML but MSBuild processor has itself has multiple phases. Here is an excerpt from amazing book "Inside the Microsoft Build Engine" by Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi and William Bartholomew:

> When the MSBuild engine begins to process a build file, it is evaluated in a top-down fashion
>   in a multi-pass manner. These passes are described in order in the following list.
>
> 0 . Load all environment and global properties
>
> 1. Evaluate properties and imports processing imports as encountered
> 2. Evaluate item definitions
> 3. Evaluate items
> 4. Evaluate using tasks
> 5. Start build and reading targets

This means that the last value of the property will win (the one which will be evaluated last). Many properties are written carefully with conditions to evaluate to this value only if no property with same name exists e.g.:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PlatformToolset Condition="$(PlatformToolset)== ''">v10_Toolset</PlatformToolset>
<PropertyGroup>
```

This approach guarantees the following: this property will have certain (*first met default*) value before phase 5, but Condition clause allows usage of Global properties and environment variables (read - your build environment parameters) to override any default values.

And thus (and it might be very confusing and counter-intuitive) if you want to say "the final word" of what property value should be - you must put it to the very end of the script.

On other hand - your described behaviour means that in your included scripts something doesn't respect existing supplied properties (e.g. doesn't have this Condition clause ) - it might be a bug in one of your scripts or intentionally overridden behaviour. I'd recommend you to find out why exactly your initial values are being changed, otherwise you can get very subtle and tricky bugs.

PS: I also accept that there might be bugs in MSBuild targets - I found that MSBuild targets quality varies slightly from "great and working perfectly" to "tangled mess" so don't be surprised if you'll see bugged\hacky approach and you'll need to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I've found, and reported in other posts tagged msbuild, that the PlatformToolset behaves funny, and different in VS or command-line. In addition to making sure it's set early enough, it seems to "unnaturally" be required in the main (not included) file and possibly in a particular spot.

Make your modular include verify that it's already correct. Then at least you can make a change in one place that makes sure you updated every project.

Even without this one being funny, the value is *used* early on, so must be set before the workhorse includes.  Prop sheets set in the IDE are put at the bottom, so that won't work.

Comment: Yep, basically all properties that have Label="Configuration" are special properties. User prop sheets (that come after the workhorse) avoid overriding them. That's why general_ps.xml (instead of general.xml) is used for the General prop page in user property sheets.